# Displaying two inline elements of the form, in responsive way (resizing)

Tags: css

It's my first time with forms, CSS and HTML, and I'm havin a trouble trying to display two elements inline, keeping in mind that they must cover all the width of the window. E.g.

[image]

So, imagine you have the following content:

```
<form>
    <fieldset> 
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input> </input>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <label>URL:</label></br>
        <input id="url" type="url" placeholder="wikipedia.org" required>
        <button id="btnBrowse" type="submit"></button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this style:

```
input {
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
#btnBrowse {
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    background: url('http://www.endlessicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/search-icon-614x460.png') no-repeat left top, orange !important;
    background-size: cover !important; 
    float: right;
}
```

I need all the input to refill the space other components left in the line. In the first fieldset there is a problem, because the 100% is according to the fieldset, so it is so long for the left space. And in the second case, the button is not of the same height...

Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/o5L8yw1s/5/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

1. On window resize, the search bars resizes.
2. Added a search button with animation using CSS transitions.

### Working Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/EDp8R/5448/embedded/result/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box1">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Enter your Username"></input>
        </fieldset>
    <div class="box2">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Url:</label>
            <input id="url" type="url" class="textbox" placeholder="http://www.example.com/"></input>
            <button id="searchBtn" class="searchBtn active" type="submit"></button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    height: 55px;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
    overflow: visible;
}

.box1, .box2 {
    height: 55px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.box1 {
    background: #ccb;
    width: 35%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box2 {
    background: #ccb;
    width: 60%;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

label {
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #aa9;
}

input {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 230px;
    top: 12px;
    height: 27px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#url {
    width: 400px;
}

button.searchBtn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.35);
    transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0s;
}

button.searchBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -27px;
    background: url('http://s25.postimg.org/6cosx3023/search.png') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0s;
}

button:focus {
    outline: medium none;
}

button.active, button:hover {
    outline: 0px none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    outline: 0px none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-color: -moz-use-text-color;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer !important;
    border: medium none;
    outline: 0px none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"calibri_light-webfont";
    font-size: 1.8em;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Hi! But this doesn't resize the controls when you resize the window http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/o5L8yw1s/14/light/

Comment: I have edited my answer and changed the link to the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/EDp8R/5448/embedded/result/). Now the search bars will be resized automatically on window resize.

Answer (score -1):

Putting the divs positioned relative to a wrapper div with its position set absolute should start you in the right direction...sorry for vagueness, im on stack exchange mobile and its difficult to write detailed answers.  I can expound when I get back to a computer, although it's more likely that someone else will answer prior to that.

Answer (score -1):

In case if you do support IE8+, you can achieve this using `display: table`. Markup:

```
<div class="input-container">
  <label for="input">Name</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter name">
  <span>Submit</span>
</div>
```

and styles:

```
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-container {
  display: table;
}
.input-container label,
.input-container input,
.input-container span {
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.input-container input {
  width: 100%;
}
.input-container label,
.input-container span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 1%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Example is [here](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/iEAyg)

Comment: Hi! This doesn't resize the controls when the window does. http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/iEAyg

Comment: Some basic styles and above example is responsive now.